# validation form javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

this is my first post here and I hope you'll be able to helpe me. Thanks in advance :).

Basically I'm trying to create a validation form, but for some reason it doesn't work at all, this is the code:

```
html:<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">    
    <head> 
        <title>Application form</title> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <meta name="description" content="Form"> 
        <meta name="keywords" content="Name, number, email, details...">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="validation.css" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>   
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>London Flight Agency</h3>           

            <form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Personal Details</legend>     
                        <select id="title">
                            <option value="Title">Title</option>
                            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                            <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                         </select>  
                         <br>                       
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                              <td><label for="name"><p>First Name:<sup>*</sup></p></label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="validateName(name)"/></td>
                              <p id="nameError" style="display: none;">You can only use letters!</p>
                            </tr>  

                            <tr>
                              <td><label for="lname"><p>Last Name:<sup>*</sup></p></label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" onblur="validatelName(lname)"/></td>
                              <p id="lnameError" style="display: none;">You can only use letters!</p>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>          
                              <td><label for="date"><p>Date of birth:<sup>*</sup></p></label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="date" id="date" onblur="validateDate(date)"/></td>
                              <p id="dateError" style="display: none;">You must enter date of birth!</p>
                            </tr>     

                            <tr>
                              <td><label for="tel"><p>Contact tel:<sup>*</sup></p></label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" onblur="validateTel(tel)"/></td>
                              <p id="telError" style="display: none;">Enter a valid telephone number!</p>
                            </tr>  

                            <tr>  
                              <td><label for="email"><p>Email Adress:<sup>*</sup></p></label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="validateEmail(email)"/></td>
                              <p id="emailError" style="display: none;">You must enter a valid email address</p>
                            </tr>  

                            <tr>
                              <td><label for="pcode"><p>Postcode:<sup>*</sup></p></label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="pcode" id="pcode" onblur="validatePcode(pcode)"/></td>
                              <p id="pcodeError" style="display: none;">You must enter a valid postcode</p>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                </fieldset> 

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Flight Details</legend>    
                         <label for="luggage"><p>Hand luggage:<sup>*</sup></p></label>

                                <input type="radio" name="luggage" value="Yes" id="yes" />
                                <label for="yes">Yes</label>

                                <input type="radio" name="luggage" id="no" value="no" />
                                <label for="no">No</label><br><br>                          

                            <table>  
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label for="height">Height:</label></td>
                                    <td><input id="height" type="text" name="height"/></td>
                                    <td><label for="height">Units:</label></td>
                                    <td><select id="height" name="height">
                                      <option>inches</option>
                                      <option>centimeters</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <br>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label for="weight">Weight:</label></td>
                                    <td><input id="weight" type="text" name="weight"/></td>
                                    <td><label for="weight">Units:</label></td>
                                    <td><select id="weight" name="weight">
                                      <option>pounds</option>
                                      <option>kilograms</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                </tr>                             
                            </table>      
                                <br>

                                <label for='extrabag'>Include extra bag(£25)</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="includebag"name="extrabag" onclick="calculateTotal()"/>

                                <br><br>

                                <label for='insurance'>Include insurance(£15)</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Insurance"name="insurance" onclick="calculateTotal()"/>                              
                                <br><br>

                                <label for='assistance'>Special assistance(£30)</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="Assistance"name="assistance" onclick="calculateTotal()"/>                                
                                <br><br>

                                <select id="Payment">
                                    <option value="payment">Payment card</option>
                                    <option value="Visa">Visa Debit Card</option>
                                    <option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option>
                                    <option value="Fudge">PayPal</option>
                                    <option value="Mocha">Mestro</option>
                                    <option value="Raspberry">Visa Electron</option>                            
                                </select>                               
                                <br><br>                                
                                <input type="submit" value="Total" />
                                <input type="reset" value="Reset form" />                           
                </fieldset>     
            </form> 


    </body>

javascript:
function validateName(name){

      var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;

      if(re.test(document.getElementById(name).value)){

        document.getElementById(name).style.background ='#ccffcc';

        document.getElementById(name + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;

        }
        else{

        document.getElementById(name).style.background ='#e35152';

        document.getElementById(name + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false; 
      }

    }

function validatelName(lname){

      var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;

      if(re.test(document.getElementById(lname).value)){

        document.getElementById(lname).style.background ='#ccffcc';

        document.getElementById(lname + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{

        document.getElementById(lname).style.background ='#e35152';

        document.getElementById(lname + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false; 
      }

    }

function validateDate(date){

      var re = ^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$;

      if(re.test(document.getElementById(date).value)){

        document.getElementById(date).style.background ='#ccffcc';

        document.getElementById(date + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }
        else{

        document.getElementById(date).style.background ='#e35152';

        document.getElementById(date + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false; 
      }

    }    

function validateNum(tel){

      var re = /^[0-9]+$/;

      if(re.test(document.getElementById(tel).value)){

        document.getElementById(tel).style.background ='#ccffcc';

        document.getElementById(tel + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{

        document.getElementById(tel).style.background ='#e35152';

        document.getElementById(tel + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false; 
      }

    }

function validateEmail(email){ 
      var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
      if(re.test(email)){
        document.getElementById('email').style.background ='#ccffcc';
        document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{
        document.getElementById('email').style.background ='#e35152';
        return false;
      }
    }


function validateForm(){
      // Set error catcher
      var error = 0;
      // Check name
      if(!validateName('name')){
        document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }

      if(!validatelName('lname')){
        document.getElementById('lnameError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }

      if(!validateNum('tel')){
        document.getElementById('telError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }

      if(!validateDate('date')){
        document.getElementById('dateError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }



      // Validate email
      if(!validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)){
        document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }    

      if(error > 0){
         return false;
          }
 }
```

I tried to modify the code several times but nothing. I reckon it's just a small error but I really don't know where it is :(

Comment: onsubmit="return validateForm()" should be onsubmit="validateForm()" you don't need the return

Comment: define "not working", also try to give us "the smallest amount of code to reproduce the error"

Comment: @Michel Channey: Sure he could use jquery but does he really need this big overhead? Although learning pure js is great as well.
Moussawi7: Please read again your answer and consult google with it, you will see that return function() is right here ;)
NDM: You can easily paste the code in a new html file and put the script tags around the last section and you will see the error

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your javascript: In function validateDate near your pattern: There are missing the regex delimiters: /^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$/;

Use an editor with syntax highlighting and a javascript debugger ;)

Comment: Would be great if you could mark my answer as the solution if it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

*MasterD* is correct and also **validateTel()** & **validatePcode()** functions are missing.